# Is there any good practice of using knockout subscribe function in magento?

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

Hi I am a newbie of developing magento pluin and I found that the knockoutjs is cool on tracking the variable state changed and you can add subscription on observable variable to fire customize code when the value is changed.

However I also got an headache on tracing the code due to the variable can be subscribed everywhere in the project, and sometimes even got some looping problem of caused by multiple subscribes of variable are affecting each other and fall into a circular sequence.

e.g.

```
a = ko.subscribe((a)=>{
    ..... other code
    b(someValue)

});


b.subscribe((b) => {
   .....other code
   a(someValue)
});
```

Is there any one know any tools can help for debuging or any good practice or suggestion for developing with knockoutjs in magento?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that's not on the Knockout's hand, because if the observable is updated it'll trigger the subscribe for everyone that is whatching.

In this case the problem is probably on your logic, you'll need to understand how can you avoid it, maybe using some if conditions inside the subcribe event.

You can also provide an real example here that is causing the loop so that we can think in a better solution